# The view properties do not appear in the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been struggling since I started programming on iOS with the use of Pods in projects, an example is when I install Floaty Pod without problems and when I use it, I do not see the properties of the view so I can give it design to my button.

[image]

I have pointed to the class that belongs in the following way, but I can not make the properties appear.

[image]

This should appear but I can not find out why it does not appear in this way how it is displayed in the Github repository https://github.com/kciter/Floaty:

[image]

This not only happens with this library but also all the ones I have installed, such as those of MaterialComponents, someone can help me please if something similar has happened to me since I have been struggling with it for some time and I can not find a root solution.

- The Xcode version is: Version 10.1 (10B61)
- The version of cocoapods is: cocoapods-1.5.3
- The ruby ​​version is: ruby ​​2.3.7p456.

Comment: There are several issues with IBDesignable classes imported from Cocoapods. You can track the [issue on the project's repo here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5334). One thing you could easily try is to subclass the component and use _your_ class in the InterfaceBuilder instead. Not tested but probably worths a try.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a Cocoapods issue but a problem in the Floating.swift file of this project. I just made a pull request for this bug on Github. It seems like changing:

```
  @IBInspectable
  @objc open var autoCloseOnTap: Bool = true
```

to:

```
  @objc @IBInspectable
  open var autoCloseOnTap: Bool = true
```

fixes the issue.

If someone has an explanation for this, I would be grateful.

Comment: ...a problem in the Floaty.swift, sorry.

Comment: This doesn't explain though why the other modules do not work either...

Comment: The [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5334) that you mention concerns the beta release of Cocoapods v1.0 (of 2016 - Cocoapods is now v1.5.2), where IBInspectables were not displayed anymore in Playgrounds. Maybe it's still the case, but it's not related to @Carlos 's issue anyway

Comment: Sorry... I don't follow. The question is _not_ about "Floaty"; it explicitly mentions that the same problem exists for several cocoapods-imported modules... All I said is that your answer doesn't address this...

Comment: Ok, apologies! I should have read the question once more, you're right!